# How do I set the tick and label colours in mplfinance?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I have managed to colour coordinate most of my mplfinance chart but I cannot seeem to figure out how to set the colour of the tick and labels.
[image]

I currently have the following code:

```
market_colours = mpf.make_marketcolors(up="g", down="r", edge=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, wick=LINE_COLOUR)
style = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=market_colours, facecolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, edgecolor=LINE_COLOUR,
                           figcolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, gridcolor=LINE_COLOUR, gridstyle="--")

mpf.plot(df, type="candle", style=style)
```

This is my code in matplotlib to do this usually:

```
ax.xaxis.label.set_color(TEXT_COLOUR)
ax.yaxis.label.set_color(TEXT_COLOUR)
for axis in ["left"]:  # modify borders
    ax.spines[axis].set_color(LINE_COLOUR)
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(3)
for axis in ["top", "right", "bottom"]:  # remove borders
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(0)
for axis in ["x", "y"]:
    ax.tick_params(axis=axis, colors=LINE_COLOUR, which="both", width=2)
```

The answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714154/matplotlib-mplfinance-how-to-change-colour-of-lines-and-bars) shows the possible kwargs for `mpf.plot` but I cannot find anything to do this, or in [the styling documentation for mplfinance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/styles.ipynb).

Edit:
Using Mr.T's solution I found also the `rcparam` `axes.labelcolor` and set it to my `TEXT_COLOUR` in the dictionary. Complete solution:

```
market_colours = mpf.make_marketcolors(up="g", down="r",
                                       edge=BACKGROUND_COLOUR,
                                       wick=LINE_COLOUR)

STYLE_DICT = {"xtick.color": LINE_COLOUR,
              "ytick.color": LINE_COLOUR,
              "xtick.labelcolor": TEXT_COLOUR,
              "ytick.labelcolor": TEXT_COLOUR,
              "axes.spines.top": False,
              "axes.spines.right": False,
              "axes.labelcolor": TEXT_COLOUR}

style = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=market_colours,
                           facecolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR,
                           edgecolor=LINE_COLOUR,
                           figcolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR,
                           gridcolor=LINE_COLOUR,
                           gridstyle="--",
                           rc=STYLE_DICT)

mpf.plot(df, type="candle", style=style)
```

Final effect:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not very familiar with `mplfinance`, so there might be better ways to address this problem. I think Daniel Goldfarb who maintains `mplfinance` checks these questions regularly and might enlighten us about better ways.

I also did not find a direct way to define these image aspects, and unfortunately, `mplfinance` does not return the axes objects it creates, so we cannot retrospectively change image elements. However, [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/styles.ipynb) it says that you can provide `rcparams` as a dictionary. Matplotlib uses `rcparams` to generate the style used for the standard or current plot. If we do this, we can modify certain image elements as you did in your matplotlib code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('examples/data/SP500_NOV2019_Hist.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df.index.name = 'Date'

BACKGROUND_COLOUR="black"
LINE_COLOUR = "blue"
TEXT_COLOUR = "orange"

style_dic = {"xtick.color": LINE_COLOUR, 
             "ytick.color": LINE_COLOUR, 
             "xtick.labelcolor": TEXT_COLOUR, 
             "ytick.labelcolor": TEXT_COLOUR,
             "axes.spines.top": False, 
             "axes.spines.right": False}

market_colours = mpf.make_marketcolors(up="g", down="r", edge=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, wick=LINE_COLOUR)
style = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=market_colours, facecolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, edgecolor=LINE_COLOUR,
                           figcolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, gridcolor=LINE_COLOUR, gridstyle="--", rc=style_dic)

mpf.plot(df, type="candle", style=style)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

I have only included in this sample code a `style_dic` dictionary with easily found `rcparams`, and I have the impression that you will not be able to alter all desired image aspects with this strategy. A list of the `rcparams` can be found [here in the matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-default-matplotlibrc-file).

Answer (score 0):

Since mplfinance provides a style function, it is easy to select your favorite style from the default styles and customize it based on the selected style.

- 'mike' Style settings

```
style = dict(style_name    = 'mike',
             base_mpl_style= 'dark_background', 
             marketcolors  = {'candle'  : {'up':'#000000', 'down':'#0080ff'},
                              'edge'    : {'up':'#ffffff', 'down':'#0080ff'},
                              'wick'    : {'up':'#ffffff', 'down':'#ffffff'},
                              'ohlc'    : {'up':'#ffffff', 'down':'#ffffff'},
                              'volume'  : {'up':'#7189aa', 'down':'#7189aa'},
                              'vcdopcod': False, # Volume Color Depends On Price Change On Day
                              'alpha'   : 1.0,
                             },
             mavcolors     = ['#ec009c','#78ff8f','#fcf120'],
             y_on_right    = True,
             gridcolor     = None,
             gridstyle     = None,
             facecolor     = None,
             rc            = [ ('axes.edgecolor'  , 'white'   ),
                               ('axes.linewidth'  ,  1.5      ),
                               ('axes.labelsize'  , 'large'   ),
                               ('axes.labelweight', 'semibold'),
                               ('axes.grid'       , True      ),
                               ('axes.grid.axis'  , 'both'    ),
                               ('axes.grid.which' , 'major'   ),
                               ('grid.alpha'      ,  0.9      ),
                               ('grid.color'      , '#b0b0b0' ),
                               ('grid.linestyle'  , '--'      ),
                               ('grid.linewidth'  ,  0.8      ),
                               ('figure.facecolor', '#0a0a0a' ),
                               ('patch.linewidth' ,  1.0      ),
                               ('lines.linewidth' ,  1.0      ),
                               ('font.weight'     , 'medium'  ),
                               ('font.size'       ,  10.0     ),
                               ('figure.titlesize', 'x-large' ),
                               ('figure.titleweight','semibold'),
                             ],
             base_mpf_style= 'mike'
            )
```

**EDIT**

Change the color of the ticks and labels, which is your choice based on this style.

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-10-01", end="2021-12-31")

my_style = mpf.make_mpf_style(base_mpf_style='mike',
                              base_mpl_style='dark_background',
                              marketcolors=mpf.make_marketcolors(up='g',down='r',
                                                                 edge='white',
                                                                 wick={'up':'g','down':'r'},
                                                                 volume='gray',
                                                                 ohlc='white'),
                              gridcolor='white',
                              gridstyle="--",
                              rc={'xtick.color':'yellow',
                                  'ytick.color':'yellow',
                                  'axes.labelcolor':'yellow' 
                                 }
                             )

mpf.plot(df, type="candle", style=my_style, figratio=(9,6))
```

[image]

Comment: The aspect ratio of the graph can be set to your liking in `figratio`. Please try to create a style that you like. If my answers were helpful to you, please click the check mark next to the answer to accept the answer.