# How do I scale mplfinance graph within Tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

With the help of [my post earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805395/how-do-i-set-the-tick-and-label-colours-in-mplfinance), I have managed to turn my chart into a candlestick one. However I cannot seem to adjust the size of it.

Old chart:
[image]

New Chart:
[image]

I'd like to resize it to how it was before. I have tried adding the following to rcparams but it had no effect:

```
"figure.figsize": figure_size,
"savefig.bbox": "tight"
```

My old relevant code:

```
figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(0.7 * res_width / 100, 0.45 * res_height / 100), facecolor=BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
ax = figure.add_subplot(111, fc=BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
figure.tight_layout()
figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=1.0, bottom=0.0, top=1.0)
FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self).get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.02, rely=0.27)
```

My current code:

```
market_colours = mpf.make_marketcolors(up="g", down="r",
                                           edge=background_colour,
                                           wick=line_colour)

style_dict = {"xtick.color": line_colour,
                  "ytick.color": line_colour,
                  "xtick.labelcolor": text_colour,
                  "ytick.labelcolor": text_colour,
                  "axes.spines.top": False,
                  "axes.spines.right": False,
                  "axes.labelcolor": text_colour}

style = mpf.make_mpf_style(marketcolors=market_colours,
                               facecolor=background_colour,
                               edgecolor=line_colour,
                               figcolor=background_colour,
                               gridcolor=line_colour,
                               gridstyle="--",
                               rc=style_dict)

figure, ax = mpf.plot(df, type="candle", returnfig=True, style=style, TEXT_COLOUR))
FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self).get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.02, rely=0.27)
```

When trying `.pack(expand=True)` on the widget it also doesn't work.
[image]

Edit:
Thanks to Mr Goldfarb I have got the graph to be bigger, but it still does not fit right. Is there a way I can apply the `figure.tight_layout()` along with `figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=1.0, bottom=0.0, top=1.0)` that I usually add?
[image]

Comment: Try using the pack manager instead of the place manager in the last line i.e. ```FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self).get_tk_widget().pack(expand = true)``` and see if it works (```expand = true``` is optional. It just tells the widget to take all the available space). But, remember, this may cause you to make minor changes in positioning widgets as you are, after all, using a different geometry manager.

Comment: @Grasshopper That had no effect on the scale of the graph, please see my edit to the post.

Comment: Just to be clear (I am not very familiar with Tkinter), regarding [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3zj6.jpg) and [this other image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgFl1.jpg), is it correct that both images show **three** separate matplotlib **Figures** embedded into a Tkinter screen?  (Asking because I don't see the code for the "Volume($)" plot nor for the "RSI(%)" plot.  Just want to confirm that I am understanding correctly what I am looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the figure size with kwarg `figsize=(width,height)` in your call to `mpf.plot()`.  Instead of:

```py
figure, ax = mpf.plot(df, type="candle", returnfig=True, style=style, TEXT_COLOUR)
```

Try

```py
figure, ax = mpf.plot(df, type="candle", returnfig=True, style=style, TEXT_COLOUR,
                      figsize=(0.7*res_width/100, 0.45*res_height/100) )
```

---

Regarding `Figure.tight_layout()` and `Figure.subplots_adjust()` ... mplfinance uses matplotlib's `Figure.add_axes()` to create Axes objects, and apparently, although `add_axes()` is part of matplotlib, the Axes that are created by `add_axes()` are incompatible with matplotlib's `tight_layout`.  I do not know if `subplots_adjust()` will work either (as I've never tried it).

That said, mplfinance implements it's own tight_layout.  Just set kwarg `tight_layout=True` when calling `mpf.plot()`.  Try that first, but if that doesn't satisfy what you are trying to accomplish, then try using [**the `scale_padding` kwarg**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/212#issuecomment-655603896).

Comment: Thank you Mr Goldfarb, this worked, however I'm still having issues with the tight layout for it to fit correctly, this has been edited into my question.